# Why is parameter identification defined on the distribution of observables, rather than just the sample?

Tags: intuition, nonparametric, identifiability

I'm struggling to intuitively understand parameter estimation.

Specifically, why do we say that a parameter is identified if it is determined by the probability distributions of observables? e.g. we say that in the linear model $y=X\beta +u$ is identified by $\beta= E(X^TX)^{-1}E(X^Ty)$.

Why don't we say that the parameter is identified if the estimate is well defined? i.e. $\hat \beta =(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty$ is well defined?

**I must be intuitively missing something, because it seems to me that an actual parameter (i.e. not the estimate), already "exists", so it doesn't need to be "identified".** On the other hand, an estimate for a parameter may not be well defined, so we need to worry that we can "identify" the parameter.

**EDIT**: I'm wondering why it would even be a problem if a parameter was unidentifiable, for example in the case of instrumental variable estimation (which is the context where I was introduced to this concept). Because so long as the estimate of a parameter is well defined, then why do we care if the actual parameter is unidentified? if there are multiple values consistent with the same distribution, then we can simply pick one of those values, and it doesn't matter. Therefore as long as we have a good estimator, we will be able to estimate one of those parameter-values. Correct?

Answer (score 1):

Imagine that you are looking at a binomial distribution $Y \sim \text{Bin}(n, \pi)$ parameterized in terms of the log-odds of an event $\theta:=\log \pi / \log (1-\pi)$.

For a sample with $n=0$, all parameter values explain the (non-existant) data equally well. For $n=1$ a finite maximum likelihood estimate (MLE) does not exist for the parameter $\theta$. Even if you paramterize in terms of $\pi$ the MLE is either $0$ (for $y=0$) or $1$ (for $y=1$). For $n=2$ the MLE is only finite for $y=1$ etc., i.e. to some extent there are always some problems with finite samples. Another example would be estimating a mean and a standard deviation for a normal distribution when you have only a single data point.

This does not mean that with more and more data you cannot learn more and more about the parameter $\theta$ (or $\pi$) - leaving aside issues for $\pi=0$ or $1$. I.e. for any $\theta \in (-\infty, \infty)$ you get all the nice asymptotic properties for MLEs as $n\to \infty$. This is what parameter identifiability means.

On the other hand, if you have a random variable defined as $Y' \sim Bin(n, a\times b)$ for some $a \in [0,1]$ and $b \in [0,1]$, the likelihood of the parameters $a$ and $b$ will have the same value for a whole curve of values no matter what data you observe (leaving aside the case with $y'=0$ or $y'=n$). I.e. any values of $a$ and $b$ that keep $a\times b$ constant result in the same distribution for $Y'$. This cannot be resolved no matter how large your sample size $n$ gets. This is the sense, in which parameter non-identfiability is meant.

Comment: Thank you. This still leaves me with the question, why would this ever be a problem in practice? why would one ever define a probability distribution as a function of two parameters $a\times b$? I have never seen this before. I've always only seen a distriubtion defined by a single parameter per relevant moment for example (i.e. the mean and variance for a normal distribution). Why would we worry about this?

Comment: Also, I'm wondering why it would even be a problem if a parameter was unidentifiable, for example in the case of instrumental variable estimation (which is the context where I was introduced to this concept). Because so long as the **estimate** of a parameter is well defined, then why do we care if the actual parameter is unidentified? if there are multiple values consistent with the same distribution, then we can simply pick one of those values, and it doesn't matter. Therefore as long as we have a good estimator, we will be able to estimate **one of** those parameter-values. Correct?

Comment: To give a more realistic example, let's say that you assume that components fail over time according to a Weibull distribution that has a scale and a shape distribution. However, you only observe at a single time (e.g. 1 year), how many components have failed (after all being in good working order to start with) and you have no other information. In that case an infinite number of combinations of scale and shape parameters are equally consistent with the data. I.e. the estimate of the parameter is not well-defined in the sense that there is no parameter estimate that is "better" than another.

Comment: If you then want to project to the future (e.g. to 2 or 10 years), it turns out that just about any projection is consistent with the data. Sure, you could pick one particular parameter vector (in a more justifiable manner if you have prior information and turn Bayesian). However, if it is a completely arbitrary pick, would you feel good, if someone had extrapolated the failure rate in the parts of the jet engine of your plane in this way and perhaps picked the value that minimized maintenance costs (perhaps the one were the shape is so that hardly any more failures occur after 1 year)?

Comment: But if you simultaneously estimate both the scale and shape parameter, and in such a way that the combined estimate of them will be consistent for a combination of scale and shape parameters that are consistent with the data, then you wouldn't have a problem right? The problem only arises when one of the parameters is estimated separately?

Comment: If you are happy that your estimate is a whole curve (infinitely many values), then in a way you are fine. I suppose looking at them separately is indeed even worse (you get an estimate of anything in $(0,\infty)$, while when estimating jointly at least you get a curve). However, you cannot get a single vector of scale and shape parameter that is in some sense a better vector than an infinite number of other ones.

Comment: Isn't any estimate of combination of scale and shape parameters that is closer to the curve of scale and shape parameters (that are defined by the probability distribution), better than those that are farther away, in the same way that any estimate of a single parameter is better if it is closer to the true one?

Comment: Sure. It simply does not mean that with more data you will more and more be able to narrow it down to a single vector (which is essentially what parameter identifiability would imply).